# How shall one implement the null object pattern in generics?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, null

I like the idea of the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and force me to use it until it really feels normal and good. At the moment I don't see how to use it in generic types. I know the possibility to define a second generic type and to pass in the class to construct a default object, but this feels really too much overhead for this pattern. Is there a good way?

```
public class GenericExample<T> {
    public static final GenericExample NULL = ???;

    private T attribute;

    public GenericExample(T attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }
}

public class HoldGeneric {
    private GenericExample<String> name = GenericExample.NULL;

    public initLater(String name) {
        this.name = new GenericExample<String>(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Guava has a solution (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)

Comment: Thanks for the link, although I don't see the connection to my concrete question here.

Comment: I got it, one could really wrap class members with `Optional` too, i.e. `private Optional<T> attribute`, but this really complicates the whole handling. I think that is the strictest way to implement the null object pattern, that must be decided top level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow what the JDK does and use a static method to infer the generic type and do an unchecked cast.

`java.util.Collections` implements Null objects for empty lists and sets.  In Java Pre-generics, there is a public static field.

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList();
```

Post generics:
  There are now static methods that infer the generic type and perform the unchecked casting for you to cast it to the correct type.  The type doesn't really matter since the collections are empty but it makes the compiler happy.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the JDK. The more interesting part how to implement a `new EmptyGenericExample()` in the code of my question is not clear to me. Of course one could use `null`, see other comments...

Comment: I begin to think this should really be the only feasible null object, i.e. otherwise one should use Guava Optional.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding of your question, I would go with the following.

```
public class GenericExample<T> {

    public static final GenericExample<?> NULL = new GenericExample<Object>(new Object()) {
        public void print() {
        }
    };

    private T attribute;

    public GenericExample(T attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.print(attribute.toString());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <X> GenericExample<X> nil() {
        return (GenericExample<X>) NULL;
    }
}

public class Test {

    private static GenericExample<String> name = GenericExample.nil();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "blah";
        name.print();
        if (name == GenericExample.NULL) {
            name = new GenericExample<String>(x);
        }
        name.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not going to compile, where is `GenericExample.nil()` defined?  Assuming you actually mean `GenericExample.NULL` then you wouldn't be able to assign an `GenericExample<?>` to a `GenericExample<String>`.

Comment: Copy/paste problem, I fixed my answer.

Comment: +1 I would just pass `null` for the attribute instead of `new Object()` because that will be type unsafe if the attribute happens to get exposed (and just do `System.out.print(attribute)`).

Comment: @PaulBellora, good point, but strongly depends on the usecase. If the argument is used in the constructor, maybe it cannot be null.

Comment: @PaulBellora What do you exactly mean by type unsafe if the attribute gets exposed? I really like the idea to use a empty object, as I want to use `public GenericExample(@Nonnull T attribute)` and this would work with `new Object()`.

Comment: @jan Right now it's fine because `attribute` isn't exposed. But if there were `public T getAttribute()`, then for example a caller could do `String str = GenericExample<String>nil().getAttribute();` and that would throw a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

Without passing in the class of `T` there's no way to properly implement it.  The closest you could do, abusing type erasure, would be:

```
class GenericExample<T>
{
  private static final GenericExample<Object> NULL = new GenericExample<Object>(); 

  public static <T> GenericExample<T> nil()
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final GenericExample<T> withNarrowedType = (GenericExample<T>)NULL;
    return withNarrowedType;
  }
}
```

However, you have to accept that `GenericExample.<Apple>nil()` would be the same as `GenericExample.<Orange>nil()`.

Comment: You have the right idea, but multiple compile errors.

Comment: Sorry, I typed the answer directly here without running it through a compiler.  It would have been more useful to state what you think the compile errors are though, rather than hinting at their presence...

Comment: Gotcha, I'll just make the edits (wasn't trying to be annoying). Mainly, `null` is a keyword - I'll let you choose something else if you want.

Comment: I don't like this answer because it doesn't take into account the absence of a empty constructor in my question code. The type safe `nil()` method is nice, but my main problems arise from the absence of a default constructor. The first answer used `new Object()` too, but comments stated out to use `null` instead. But I want to use `@Nonnull` and believe it is a contradiction to use `null` to implement the null object pattern.

Comment: It depends on how you use the attribute.  You could have a method that access the attribute and if it's null throw an exception, much like Scala's Option.get does.